# Mouse wheel event does not fire on GWT FocusPanel, if FocusPanel is on GWT PopupPanel (only in Chrome and Safari)

Tags: gwt

Here's the code:

```
public class MyEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    PopupPanel      popupPanel = new PopupPanel(false,true);
    FocusPanel      focusPanel = new FocusPanel();
    VerticalPanel   popupContent = new VerticalPanel();

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        popupContent.add(new Label("Simple popup test"));
        popupContent.add(new Label("_"));

        focusPanel.add(popupContent);
        popupPanel.setWidget(focusPanel);

        popupPanel.center();

        focusPanel.addMouseWheelHandler(new MouseWheelHandler(){
            public void onMouseWheel(MouseWheelEvent event) {
                System.out.println("deltaY = " + event.getDeltaY());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

If you run a GWT app in Firefox, move your mouse over the text "Simple popup test" and scroll the mouse wheel, then onMouseWheel will be called.

If this application is running in Chrome or Safari, place your mouse over the text "Simple popup test" and scroll the mouse wheel, then onMouseWheel not called. If you place the mouse cursor is not on the GWT Label and scroll the mouse wheel, the event will be called onMouseWheel.

Maybe someone has already corrected this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bug can be found on the GWT issue tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7349

There is a link to a Google goups discussion in the issue text.

I solved the problem by set the popup to modal = false.

Comment: Yes, this has helped:
[http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7349](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7349)
Thank you very much.